# When does a cart become an abandoned cart in Magento 2?

Tags: e-commerce, magento2, cart

For a client, I am building a Magento 2 module to automatically send an abandoned cart email when certain conditions are met. I started of with testing when Magento 2 considers a cart abandoned, but simply creating a cart and leaving the page doesn't always seem to trigger the reporting process.

Does anyone have more information on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

Abandoned is **not** magento 2 **default feature**.`So, magento does not calculate a cart as abandoned or not`.

In magento,you ***can access a cart until that quote/cart has been delete from Quote at table***.

> For quest customer, a cart is active when session is expire. So,
>   Implement abandoned is totally depend on your business logic.